# Как удалить сообщение рассылки бота у всех подписчиков? (Telegram на aiogram)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, aiogram

Народ, кто знает, можно ли по аналогичной схеме задать "delete_message" вместо "send_photo" так чтобы удалить сообщение рассылки бота у всех подписчиков?? Ниже пример кода рассылки фото, работает как надо. (Telegram на aiogram)

## Получаем список подписчиков бота из базы данных

```
subscriptions = db.get_subscriptions()
```

## Отправляем всем новость тем кто подписан

```
for s in subscriptions:
    with open('X:\\TELEGRAMM\\images\\' + fname, 'rb') as photo:
    await bot.send_photo(s[1], photo, disable_notification = True)
```

Comment: а зачем его отправлять если потом нужно удалить?)

Comment: @5c0rp удалять отправленные сообщения удобная функция для администратора бота, мало ли какие косяки могут быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надеюсь правильно понял Ваш вопрос. Вроде как можно переменной присвоить отправленное сообщение `message_info = bot.message.answer("message")` и с помощью переменной извлечь message_id`message_info['message_id']` Ну а там уже с помощью метода delete_message пройтись по списку полученных айдишников.